# Add class to elements one by one jquery EDITED

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**2º EDIT**:

thought it was solved but it isn't. when a page is loaded i want to add a class to some elements(on this case is to buttons) and for now my code is:

```
        $("button").each(function(index){       
            // add the class
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).addClass("varrimento");
            }.bind(this),index*5000);
            // remove the class
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("varrimento");
            }.bind(this),(index+1)*5000); 
        });
```

This code add the class "varrimento" for 5 secs to each button one by one but it has 2 problems.

- When i change page and return to the initial page it's like the
  setTimeout of the first visit on the page it's still running, so on
  the second visit the code of "varrimento" it's added to the buttons
  again and they are not one by one like the first visit.
- In some pages, don't know why, it takes too long to adding the class
  to the elements. ex: on page "index" right after i visit page, the
  class is added immediately to the first button but changing to second
  page (code is the same, the only thing that differs is the amount of
  buttons) it takes like 15secs to the first button have the class.

Second day in a row trying to solve this problem but can't figure it out. any help guys?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)?

Answer (score 1):

Save your timeout variable in localStorage and then remove it -

```
var timeout = setTimeout(auto_reload, 90000);
    localStorage.setItem("timeout", timeout);

var timeout = localStorage.getItem("timeout");
            clearTimeout(timeout);
```